# Application labels aren't unique

Tags: django, django-views, django-settings, django-3.1

Has anybody encountered the following error? Building simple django python blog application.
[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EEAR.png)

Any ideas as to what it correlates to would be appreciated. Have not found a solution as of yet.

[INSTALLED_APPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFsXg.png)

Comment: Share the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: solved not to worry thanks, realised I had listed it in INSTALLED_APPS as well as included the +=('') below, which was not needed.